# R: When Estimating Fixed Effect Interactions, How Can I Specify Which Interactions are Omitted?

Tags: r, regression, lm

I attempt to estimate:

`OLS <- lm(Income ~ Year + State + Year:State, data=MyData)`

For issues related to collinearity, lm omits one of the years and one of the states.  This is fine, accept ideally, I would like to omit say, the first year to use as a baseline.

Is there anyway to specify which year and which state get omitted?

Comment: Why not to use `subset`, for exmaple `...data=subset(MyData,Year != firstYear & State != stateX)`?

Comment: If you have panel data, you can use `plm` package. I think it handles that.

Comment: I have not seen a way of doing this in plm - but if you know the way - please do let me know.

Comment: Please see [here](http://www.statisticsmentor.com/2012/10/30/statistics-with-r-how-to-change-the-baseline-reference-category-in-regression/) and [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/dummy_vars.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if Year and State are factors then by default the first level is "omitted" (treated as baseline). You can use `relevel` to specify another baseline level.

See

```
?relevel
```

If your model gets more complicated you may need `contrasts`.

Comment: Thank you and thanks to user Metrics.  His link lead me right to the 'relevel' command.  That does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my comment , You can use `subset` parameter of  `lm` :

> subset     an optional vector specifying a subset of observations to be
>   used in the fitting process.

For example using `mtcars` data set:

```
lm(mpg ~ wt, cyl!=6 & wt > 0, data=mtcars)
```

Comment: Subsetting will not get at it.  If one were to run this regression and enter each variable and variable interaction manually (as opposed to using the ":" operator), one could omit the baseline variable of their choice (ie. the first year).  I have too many variable interactions to build individual column vectors and enter them manually.